# append big text to jtextpane result in 'OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, heap-memory

I'm trying to append a text of a file into my JTextPane. This works great for files that are under 10Mb but for size above it (and I checked ~50Mb) I get the notorious exception 'OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'.

I'm trying to understand why do I get java heap memory if both methods are static and there's no 'new' in every iteration under the while(line!=null). If I can open the file in a regular txt editor, why does this code fail to execute?

The code looks like this:

```
public static void appendFileData(JTextPane tPane, File file) throws Exception
{
    try{

        //read file's data
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = br.readLine();

        try{ 
               while (line != null) 
               { 
                   JTextPaneUtil.appendToConsole(tPane, "\n"+line,Color.WHITE, "Verdana", 14);
                   line = br.readLine();
               } 

           }finally 
           {
               br.close();
           }

    }catch(Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

the appendToConsole is:

```
public static void appendToConsole(JTextPane console, String userText, Color color, String fontName, int fontSize)
{
  StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, color);
  aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, fontName);
  aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontSize, fontSize);
  aset = sc.addAttribute(aset,StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

  int len = console.getDocument().getLength();
  console.setCaretPosition(len);
  console.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
  console.replaceSelection(userText);
}
```

Comment: it is possibly because your file is not having a newline character (eg: binary executable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you adding attributes for every line? Swing needs to do a lot of work to either keep track of all those attributes, or merge them into one attribute for the entire file.

Try using code like the following AFTER you have loaded all the data into the text pane to set the attributes for the entire text pane at one time.

```
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

Also, I don't think you need to set the font by using attributes. You should just be able to use:

```
textPane.setFont(...);
```

Comment: I tried to keep it simple by (1) removing 'appendToConsole' (2) reading all data first into a StringBuffer and (3) writing to a document: doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n"+sb.toString(), null); the result is that I can see the text but it's to slow. Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: Try using the read() method of JTextPane. Its a large file so don't expect miracles.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your code is not explicitly calling the 'new' keyword doesn't mean that code you call isn't. I'd assume that setting the character attributes over and over each time you call `appendToConsole` is creating some underlying objects - you'd have to see the source code or run it in a profiler to be sure, though.

Also, Strings can be created without 'new', so `br.readLine()` is creating and returning a new String for each line in the source file, and appending an "\n" to it also creates another new String. And all those Strings are being added to the document model of your JTextPane, which ultimately will hold the entire contents of the file you're loading.

The default JVM heap size is around 64MB - loading a ~50MB file along with other supporting classes in the JVM and in your code is apparently putting you over that limit, and then you get an OutOfMemoryError.

To see what's really being allocated in your program, and what references are hanging around, run your program through a profiler like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).